# PHP for loops with an extra unwanted entry at the end

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to display my SQL table in 4 columns so I ran a `for` loop 4 times and another `for` loop inside (determined by how many entries there are). For some reason I keep on getting an extra empty container at the end. The database has an uneven number of entries (especially to test this scenario). See the code below:

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM allthaimgs ORDER BY id ASC")
        or die(mysqli_error());
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$thamout = $num_rows / 4;

for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < $thamout; $x++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )
            ?>
            <div class="colimgdiv">
                <img src="../imgs/galary/zoom.png" class="zoomimgincol">
                <div class="blktrsprt"></div>
                <img src="../imgs/galary/imgs/<?php echo $row["imgs"];?>" class="theimg">
            </div>
        <?php 
    }
    echo '</div><div class="column">';
}
?>
```

Comment: `'</div><div class="column">'` is causing the problem.  Change `<div class="column">` position

Comment: Where is your full code?

Comment: Thanks @JitendraSoftgrid, but that is not the problem. 
I didn't add the code above the PHP code - my bad. But it's basically just a opening DIV `<div class="column">`.

Comment: The first FOR loop starts, then enters the 'child' for loop.
The 'child' for loop runs (the amount of rows divided by 4), then exits the child loop, close the first column (which is the php echo code), and open the next column. This goes on four times.

The problem is in the last column there is an additional empty DIV ( `<div class="colimgdiv"></div>` )

Comment: Replace `$thamout = $num_rows / 4;`  with `$thamout = floor($num_rows / 4);`

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid......DUDE! exactly what I needed.Your the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in line

```
$thamout = $num_rows / 4;
```

You need to `floor` the number.

```
$thamout = floor($num_rows / 4);
```